# How to make size of label1 same as size of label2 when i tap on label2 in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have two Columns of labels.ColumnA contain five empty labels and columnB contain five labels with some random text.The ColumnA is hidden at initially, and come into view when user tap on any label from ColumnB. The size of both labels from two columns is different as the columnB size is according the text it contain but columnA has no text so its size is according to the frame. I want when i tap on any label from columnB the size of all the labels in columnA should become same as the size of tapped label, how can i get all this stuff? See this image[image]

As in this image there are different size of **blue** empty label when i tap on gray label of text **abs**.How can i got blue empty label size only same as tapped label?
Here is my code`// top of top row
    CGFloat y1 = 100.0;

```
// left of Column A
CGFloat x1 = 20.0;

// left of Column B
CGFloat x2 = 220.0;

// Vertical spacing for rows of labels
CGFloat yInc = 40.0;

// initialize a CGRect
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(x1, y1, 100, 30);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{

    // Create UILabel for Column A
    _lblA = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    _lblA.tag = 100+i;
    _lblA.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _lblA.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _lblA.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _lblA.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:17.0];
    //[self.gameLayer addSubview:_lblA];
    //lblA.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _lblA.text=[MainArrayFirst objectAtIndex:i];
    [_lblA sizeToFit];

    // "move" the rectangle, so the next label starts at column B
    rect1.origin.x = x2;

    // Create UILabel for Column B
    _lblB = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    _lblB.tag = 200+i;
     _lblB.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    _lblB.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;

    [self.gameLayer addSubview:_lblB];
    __lblB.hidden = YES;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(100,30);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [_lblA.text sizeWithFont:_lblA.font
                                      constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                          lineBreakMode:_lblA.lineBreakMode];
    CGRect newFrame = _lblA.frame;
    newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
    self.lblB.frame = newFrame;
    CGRect newFrame1 = _lblB.frame;
    newFrame1.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
    newFrame1.origin.x = _lblC.frame.origin.x + self.lblC.frame.size.width;


    // add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the label
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotTapped:)];
    [_lblB addGestureRecognizer:tap];


    // "move" the rectangle, so the next label starts at column C
    // this is the right-edge of the Column A label
    rect1.origin.x = _lblC.frame.origin.x + _lblC.frame.size.width;
    }
         - (void) gotTapped:(id)sender {
          // a label in Column A was tapped, so show Column B labels if they were hidden,
          //      or hide them if they were visible
          for (UILabel *v in _columnB) {
          v.hidden = !v.hidden;

     }
   }
```

`